# angular material2 data-table component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to implement a table component from angular material component and all good and look nice, the big problem is how to populate the table with dynamic data from DB.
I receive from DB a object array like in this example but I really don't know how to iterate this and to populate my table.

```
tablePopulate = [
    {id: ‘1’, name: ‘Jimmy’, progress: ’10%’, color: ‘blue’},
    {id: ‘2’, name: ‘John’, progress: ’40%’, color: ‘yellow’},
    {id: ‘3’, name: ‘Wright’, progress: ’70%’, color: ‘orange’}
  ];
```

here is an example with the table component:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/dnbermjydavk?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.ts

So how can I populate this table with this kind of array objects.

Thank's in advance !

Comment: check it here, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwrpz7?file=app/table-overview-example.ts

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty nice worked, can you also please clear the createNewUser function also remove those constants and add as an answer to get the points, in this comments section I cannot accept as best response.

Comment: let me do that, :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so, as as per your requirement,
Lets pass the data as you are getting , In Array Format

```
[
     {id: "1", name: "Jimmy", progress: "10", color: "blue"},
     {id: "2", name: "John", progress: "40", color: "yellow"},
     {id: "3", name: "Wright", progress: "70", color: "orange"}
  ]
```

removing `%` as its appending From HTML, You can Just Remove it from
`table-overview-example.html` Line:`20`  (Have a look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwrpz7?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.html))

pass the array inside here: `MatTableDataSource()` like below:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Data table with sorting, pagination, and filtering.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-overview-example.html',
})
export class TableOverviewExam  ple {
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'progress', 'color'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor() {


    // Assign the data to the data source for the table to render
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([
    {id: "1", name: "Jimmy", progress: "10", color: "blue"},
    {id: "2", name: "John", progress: "40", color: "yellow"},
    {id: "3", name: "Wright", progress: "70", color: "orange"}
  ]);
  }

  /**
   * Set the paginator and sort after the view init since this component will
   * be able to query its view for the initialized paginator and sort.
   */
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
}



/** Constants used to fill up our data base. */
const COLORS = ['maroon', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'olive', 'green', 'purple',
  'fuchsia', 'lime', 'teal', 'aqua', 'blue', 'navy', 'black', 'gray'];
const NAMES = ['Maia', 'Asher', 'Olivia', 'Atticus', 'Amelia', 'Jack',
  'Charlotte', 'Theodore', 'Isla', 'Oliver', 'Isabella', 'Jasper',
  'Cora', 'Levi', 'Violet', 'Arthur', 'Mia', 'Thomas', 'Elizabeth'];
```

Here is a working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwrpz7?file=app/table-overview-example.ts).

Comment: only one small thing, seems to be a problem with this line: dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserData>; Cannot find name 'UserData' :|

Comment: oops, thanks for the correction, Updated the answer. Please check once more.